# set the max date on kendo date picker from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have this:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Updating the kendo datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
    max: today.setDate(today.getDate()+30);
});
```

In the debugger the max value is `1404408808080` but in today variable the date is right one `2014-07-03T17:3`. Want to set the max date for kendodatepicker 30 days from the current date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use the [`setOptions()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/methods/setoptions) method to change that:

```
var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");

datepicker.setOptions({
    max: new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+30))
});
```

Or if you want just do this in the initialization:

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    max: new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+30))
});
```

Comment: Looks like it should also work during initial configuration as OP tried [according to the docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/datepicker#configuration-max).

Comment: how to restrict the user from manually entering a date greater than 30 days from todays date

Comment: @Kylok yes it works, indeed. I though he want to do it after the initialization. Btw, creating a new Date from `setDate()` returns is a good idea.

Comment: @user1016740 the `max` should restrict it automatically. If not, you can disable the manual input, but I guess that isn't what you want.

Comment: yes, I dont want to restrict the manual entering, whats the best way to restrict the user to enter dates lessthan max date

Comment: [Here's a useful post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-datepicker-max-and-min-values-not-limiting-text-entry) about restricting manual entry of dates outside min/max range. The short answer is it looks like you need to take care of that with your own validation code.

Comment: @Kylok that is why Kendo sucks in some ways.

Answer (score 4):

The `setDate` function returns the date as an integer (the long number you posted); try sending that as a parameter to a new Date object, like so:

```
$('#datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
    max: new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()+30));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way also

```
         var today = new Date();
         var maxDate = today.setDate(today.getDate()+30);
         $('#datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
         max: new Date(maxDate) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way (as per [Kendo](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/methods/max) document too)

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");

datepicker.max(new Date(2100, 0, 1));
</script>
```

Added a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ECAKEqoW/2) example where see how we restrict (minimum and maximum date example)  the birthdate and deceased date of a patient entry.